# Make text appear immediately on key press

Tags: python, text, enter

I'm making a text based game and I want the user to be able to press enter while the text is appearing letter by letter to make the remaining of the text appear immediately.

This is my code so far

```py
import time 
import sys 

def print(s): 
    for c in s:
        sys.stdout.write(c)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.01)
        
def sceneOne():
  print ("insert\n"
  "text\n"
  "here\n")

  
  input("\n[Press enter to continue]\n")

  print ("insert\n"
  "text\n"
  "here\n")

  input("\n[Press enter to continue]\n")

sceneOne()
```

I want the "Press enter to continue" text to be under the "insert text here" while the text is appearing letter by letter so that the user can make the text appear faster if they have already played the game and want to speed run through this part to get to the next choice faster.

Comment: My feeling is this will be hard to accomplish with the input() method, as it is meant for simple "modal" (break program flow) input tasks. Maybe this `keyboard` library will work better https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/

Comment: using normal `print()` and `input()` you can't control where you display text - you can't move to previous line to display text. On some console/terminal you may use special codes in `print()` to move cursor in any place. And this is used by modules like [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), [urwind](http://urwid.org/). Besides `input()` blocks code, and your `print()` also blocks code and they would have to run in separated threads. maybe `curses` have method to check if there is new char in input without blocking code - or look for `getchar` or `getch` in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install the keyboard module and then you can create an event listener. Then, modify the print function so that it does not sleep if they hit enter. See below:

```
def print(s): 
    for c in s:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
        else:
            sys.stdout.write(c)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.05)
```